# Databricks notebook throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` when using case classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, noclassdeffounderror

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Platform (wrong name: $lineced0c9ad1f774dd1b896de81ceff72a831/$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Platform)
```

My Databricks notebook throws this error when I try to `map` to a bunch of case classes I created. The error is listed in the common errors found in notebooks page of Databricks': https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/notebooks/common-errors-in-notebooks

The solution given there is to:

> Move the case class definition to a cell of its own.

This is what I already have in place. Also note that I'm using Scala 2.12 --- unlike the situation covered in the link.

Looking at the error, I think what is happening is that Spark's laziness causes it to store an internal reference to the case class. And when the code is finally referenced, and somehow, something is going wrong with referencing the definitions in another cell.

Note that the same code works when I plonk everything in the same cell.

The latest stack in the trace is:

```
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

Edit:

My best attempt at a minimal example that throws this error:

```scala
// Cell 1
var df_0 = spark
  .read
  .option("multiline", "false")
  .option("dropFieldIfAllNull", "true")
  .text(file)

// Cell 2
case class People(
  full_name: Option[Seq[String]]
)

// Cell 3
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import io.circe.Json
import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._
import io.circe.parser._

val transform = udf {
  x: String => {
    val json = parse(x).getOrElse(Json.Null)
    val traversal = root.full_name.each.string
    val full_names: Seq[String] = traversal.getAll(json)
    
    People(full_name = Some(full_names))
  }
}

// Cell 4
val df_1 = df_0
  .withColumn("parsed", transform(col("value")))
  .select("parsed.*")

// Cell 5
df_1
    .withColumn("full_name_exploded", explode($"full_name"))
    .groupBy("full_name_exploded")
    .count()
    .orderBy(desc("count"))
    .show(10)
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I've been struggling with coming up with a minimal example all morning as this error seems to be non-determinstic. It happens _sometimes_. I am posting the rough outline of the sequence of code that I've most often encountered this with.